# Definir duas colunas juntas como índice no springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Boa tarde!
Gostaria de saber consigo definir duas colunas juntas como índice exclusivo?

preciso que quando já existir o valor da coluna1 junto com o valor da coluna2 não deixe inserir os dados.

exemplo:

Se Coluna1  conter o valor 1 e Coluna2 o valor 2, quando tentar inserir os mesmo valores nas duas colunas não deixar.

Estou usando Spring JPA.

Obrigado

Comment: Já encontrei a resposta, Obrigado

Answer (score -2):

Atualizar : Se você precisar criar e indexar com duas ou mais colunas, você pode usar vírgulas. Por exemplo:

@Entity
@Table(name    = "company__activity",
indexes = {@Index(name = "i_company_activity", columnList = "activity_id,company_id")})
public class CompanyActivity{

Referência: https://qastack.com.br/programming/3405229/specifying-an-index-non-unique-key-using-jpa